# Amazon SageMaker multiple-models

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am interested when using Amazon Sagemaker multiple-models options running on one endpoint. How does it look in practice? When I send more requests on different models, can Sagemaker deal with this simultaneously?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which model in the request body. The model name specified when creating the sagemaker model.

- [Invoke a Multi-Model Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/invoke-multi-model-endpoint.html)

```
response = runtime_sm_client.invoke_endpoint(
                        EndpointName = ’my-endpoint’,
                        ContentType  = 'text/csv',
                        TargetModel  = ’new_york.tar.gz’,
                        Body         = body)
```

[Save on inference costs by using Amazon SageMaker multi-model endpoints](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/save-on-inference-costs-by-using-amazon-sagemaker-multi-model-endpoints/)
[image]

There are multiple limitations. Currently the sagemaker multi model server (MMS) cannot use GPU.

[Host Multiple Models with Multi-Model Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/multi-model-endpoints.html)

> Multi-model endpoints are not supported on GPU instance types.

The SageMaker Python SDK is not clear which framework model supports the multi model server deployment and how. For instance with [Use TensorFlow with the SageMaker Python SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/tensorflow/using_tf.html#deploy-tensorflow-serving-models), the SageMaker endpoint docker image is automatically picked up by SageMaker using the images in [Available Deep Learning Containers Images](https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/available_images.md). However it is not clear which framework images are MMS ready.

[Deploy Multiple ML Models on a Single Endpoint Using Multi-model Endpoints on Amazon SageMaker] explains building AWS XGBoost image with MMS. Hence apparently the docker image needs to be built with MMS being specified as the front-end. If the images are not built in such a way, MMS may not be available.

Such information is missing in AWS, so if there is an issue encountered, you would need AWS support to identify the cause. Especially SageMaker team keeps changing the images, MMS implementation, etc, there can be issues expected.

### References

- [SageMaker Inference Toolkit](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-inference-toolkit)
- [Multi Model Server](https://github.com/awslabs/multi-model-server)
- [Deploy Multiple ML Models on a Single Endpoint Using Multi-model Endpoints on Amazon SageMaker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vnkx_hOWLio)